# How to use strftime function multiple times in an awk command

Tags: awk, gawk, strftime

I want to use gawk to convert unix timestamps to a date format, using strftime.

When I use strftime once, I get the expected result:

```
$ echo 1454310000 | gawk -F "," '{$s=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", ($1), 1); $e=$s; print ($s, $e);}'
2016-02-01 07:00:00 2016-02-01 07:00:00
```

But when I use strftime multiple times, both returned results are completely wrong:

```
$ echo 1454310000 | gawk -F "," '{$s=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", ($1), 1); $e=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", ($1), 1); print ($s, $e);}'
1970-01-01 00:33:36 1970-01-01 00:33:36
```

Why is this happening and how do I correct it so I can use strftime twice on the same input?

Comment: What do you think `$e` and `$s` mean? I think you are using shell code style in `awk` code. Please, read the `awk` basic guides and learn about `awk`, because `print $n` does not print the content of the variable `n` but the **n**th-field from the input line.

Comment: When I run your `awk` code I get `fatal: 3 is invalid as number of arguments for strftime`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the usage of variables. In `awk`, variables are not referred with a leading dollar. So say yes to `var` and say no to <s>`$var`</s>:

```
$ echo 1454310000 | gawk -F "," '{s=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", ($1), 1); e=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", ($1), 1); print (s, e);}'
2016-02-01 07:00:00 2016-02-01 07:00:00
```

What was happening?

Since `s` and `e` were undefined variables, when you said `$s=something()`, you ended up assigning the output of that `something()` into `$` plus an undefined variable value, which defaults to `0`. And `$0` is the whole record, so you were assigning the value of the record itself.

See a simpler example:

```
$ echo "hello" | awk '{$s="bu"; print}'
bu
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the '$' symbols to dereference variables. Try that:

```
echo 1454310000 | gawk -F "," '{s=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", ($1), 1); e=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", ($1), 1); print (s, e);}'
```